# Score not changing when collision occurs

Tags: c#, xna

I have been trying to get my score to work correctly when the player collides with one of the collectibles but the score does not seem to change when the collision occurs, I am not sure why this is happening.

**In my collectible I have this:**

```
class BlueBall : Obj
{
    public BlueBall(Vector2 pos) 
        : base(pos)
    {
        position = pos;
        spriteName = "BlueBall";
        solid = false;
        score = 0;
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        if (!alive) return;

        Player player = CheckCollisionAgainst<Player>();
        if (player != null)
        {
            score = score + 20;
            alive = false;
        }
```

I am drawing in the `Game1` class with:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: " + score.ToString(), scorePos, Color.White);
```

So if the Player Collides with the BlueBall, 20 should be added to the score and the BlueBall should disappear, it does disappear but the score does not change, why is this?

At this moment I am declaring my score in the Game1 class with `public int score` and `Vector2 scorePos` to position it. I then Initialize the score with `score = 0;` and then Load in the scorePos values in Update.

Comment: Can you show us what score is.

Comment: @deathismyfriend for score I have just simply made `int score` and declared it then set score to 0

Comment: And where is score defined? Is that variable actually being drawn? Is it scoped properly? **Not enough code yet**.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I have edited my original post to include more code and info, hope this helps

Comment: So.... does it draw? Sounds like the draw code either isn't executing or isn't picking up the update

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes, I am drawing in Game1 with `spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: " + score.ToString(), scorePos, Color.White);`

Comment: Ok, that code should *not* compile unless there was some other "score" variable. You are changing the score variable *in the BlueBall object, not the game class*. You either need to change the score in the game object, or draw the blue ball's score.

Comment: How would I go about drawing the score in BlueBall? What would I need to put after the code in my question?

Comment: @KizzaWellz If I had to guess, you actually want the collision to raise some event that modifies the game score (does every ball *really* have its own score?) To answer your direct question, just add a "draw" method and call it from the main "draw" method. The issue here is deeper though, you need to understand variable scoping and class design. I'll think about how to formulate an answer and potentially post in a bit.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET   hmmm okay, I'll have a go at it. The player will be going around collecting the balls and each of them will have their own score.

Comment: @KizzaWellz Given that the balls are going away, they may have a score *they give to the player*, but it seems very unlikely to me that they would *increment and keep track of an individual "score"*

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm really not sure how to go about this. I had some sort of scoring working in a previous game but that was all written in the Game1 with no classes but this time I have used classes. It seemed straight forward to me, player hits blueball, score goes up but that is clearly not the case

Comment: Yeah.... please see my answer. Variable scoping is the problematic concept for you here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks, I have read through your answer but I am still unsure what code I need to include in order for the scoring to work correctly.

Comment: @KizzaWellz The full code for each of those options would make my already long answer *way* too long. Could you ask a more specific question? I added a sample of the "simple" method.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I have created a GlobalVariable class and in that i have done `public class GlobVariable { public static int score; }` with this new Glob Variable, I have gone to the BlueBall class and added a draw method (not sure whether to use public ovveride, public void... etc for that) and started a `spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: " + GlobVariable.score, scorePos, Color.White)` am I going in the right direction?

Comment: @KizzaWellz using the static variable, you wouldn't put a draw method in the ball class for score (though you may have one for other reasons). Just reference the static variable direclty

Comment: @BradleyDotNET just one slight problem, the scoring is working and adding 20 for the blueball but when i go to collect another collectible, say yellowball, the score does not change from 20 to 40

Comment: @KizzaWellz Did you do a `+=` on the score? If you did `=` that would cause the problem you are seeing

Comment: @BradleyDotNET above comment is me being stupid, i forgot to change one score to GlobVariable.score, ignore me haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, and your comments, it is clear that there are actually **two** score variables. One that is owned by the game:

```
public class Game
{
    private int score;

    void Draw(...)
    {
       spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: " + score.ToString(), scorePos, Color.White);
    }
}
```

and one that is owned by the *ball*:

```
public class BlueBall : Obj
{
    private int score;

    public void CheckCollisions()
    {
        if (collision)
           score += 20;
    }
}
```

Now, those two score variables **have absolutely no relation to each other**. The fact that they are named the same **is totally irrelevant**.

To make a quick analogy, imagine programming objects are boxes. Each variable is a "counter". You put a counter in the "Game" box and call it "score". You put *another* counter in the "Ball" box and also call it "score". Obviously, modifying the counter in the "Ball" box won't affect the one in the "Game" box and vice versa. In general, this concept is called "scoping" in programming. Each variable is scoped to its box, which can be a class, function, or even a using block (scopes are created by `{}`).

Now that you understand the problem, there are a couple ways to fix it:

1. Create a *global* variable. You can't actually do that in C#, but you can create another object that both other objects have access to. Both objects than reference/modify it's "score" property. A simple (and poor practice) example would be:

   ```
   public static class GlobalState
   {
       public static int GameScore { get; set; }
   }
   ```

All references to score would become `GlobalState.GameScore`. Again, this is just to get you going, this kind of code *is really bad practice, and can cause bugs (especially in multi-threaded situations)*.

2. Have the ball raise an event on collision. The game would register for this event and increment its "score" variable appropriately.
3. Pass the game's "score" variable to the collision method by ref, so that it can change it. **Warning: This is included for completeness, and this should only be done in specific circumstances, of which yours is probably not one of them.**
4. Pass a delegate to the ball on creation to invoke when it needs to increment the score. This is really a variation of the event method.

I'm sure there are others. Given your experience level, I would *start* with the global approach (as its the simplest and requires the least amount of knowledge) and then move to learning about events and go with that approach in the future.

Comment: I'm still not really sure how to implement this into the code that I already have. I have made the new public static class for the Variable but I dont know what to do after

Comment: @KizzaWellz think about it.  Why would a players score be tracked inside of the `BlueBall` object? And why would the `Game1` object store a player's score? `Player` should have a public `Score` property, and you should be updating that on collision.

Comment: @KizzaWellz Also, I said what to do after, update your uses of `score` to the static variable. NETScape is right though, a Player object would be a better design than what you have.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET okay I have managed to get the score to change. Thanks for the help, appreciate it